# How to lock a column in Kendo UI Vue Grid (native)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to pin/lock a column to the left hand side using the **Native Grid**

I want to avoid using the Wrapper because my table is dynamical configured by the end user. The problem is that the property `locked` seems to be ignored completely.

HTML

```
<Grid ref="grid" 
  :style="{height: 'auto'}" 
  :data-items="items" 
  :resizable="true" 
  :columns="columns" 
  :edit-field="'inEdit'"></Grid>
```

Data

```
items = [
  {"column1": "1", "inEdit": true},
  {"column1": "2", "inEdit": true},
  {"column1": "3", "inEdit": true}
];
columns = [{
    "minResizableWidth": 50,
    "width": 100,
    "title": "Column 1",
    "field": "column1",
    "sortable": true,
    "editable": true,
    "locked": true,
    "editor": "text"
  },
  {
    "minResizableWidth": 50,
    "width": 200,
    "title": "Column 2",
    "field": "column2",
    "sortable": true,
    "editable": true,
    "editor": "text"
  },
  {
    "minResizableWidth": 50,
    "width": 200,
    "title": "Column 3",
    "field": "column3",
    "sortable": true,
    "editable": true,
    "editor": "text"
  }
];
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locked columns in Kendo UI Vue Grid (native) where just released and you can check a demo in this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tbawvj?file=index.html).

(initial answer) Locked columns are not yet available in the new Kendo Native (no depending on jQuery) Vue Grid yet they are already in a 'ready for test' state and will probably be available next week. I will update my answer once this feature is out.

Comment: Please do. Thanks